# How to stop infinite loop caused by callback in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have two async functions defined in my program; one of them pings a given IP address(using the [net-ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping) module) and 'returns' (through a callback) whether the ping was successful, and the other creates an SSH connection to a given IP address (using the [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module) and also 'returns' whether the connection was successful or not.

My problem arises when I try to read in IP data from a `data.txt` file using the `readline` functionality. I use `readline` module to read in each line from the file, use the callbacks to call ping and ssh in a blocking fashion, and then place these return values into an array to use later. I've been able to verify that the functions are executed in the order I expect, and that the return values are truly returned.. However, when the program reaches the end of the file - instead of terminating, it just reads the file again, and again, and again.

The SSH function is defined as:

```
function SSH(ipAdress, callback) {

  connection.on('ready', function(err) {

    if(err) {
      throw err;
      returnValue = "ErrorWithReadyConnection";
      callback(null, returnValue);
    }

    //runs the uptime command once we have SSH'd into the machine
    connection.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) { 

      if(err) {
        throw err;
        returnValue = "ErrorRunningCommandFromSSH";
        callback(null, returnValue);

      }
      else {

        stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {

          //code holds the response from running 'uptime'
          console.log("Stream on close. Code : " + code +
                      ". Signal: " + signal);

          connection.end();
          returnValue = "success";
          callback(null, returnValue);

      }).on('data', function(data) {

       console.log("STDOUT: " + data);
      }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {

          console.log("STDERR: " + data);
        });
      }
    }); 

  //Parameters for the SSH connection
  }).connect({
    host: ip,
    port: 22,
    username: userName,
    privateKey: privateKey,
    passphrase: passPhrase
  }); //connect


  //handle any connection errors done whilst creating a connection
  connection.on('error', function(err) {

    if(err) {
      returnString = "ErrorWaitingForHandshake";
      callback(null, returnString);
    }
  }); //end connect
}
```

The ping function is defined as:

```
function pingFunc(ip, callback) {

  var returnString;

  //Create a ping session, passing the IP of the machine to ping
  sessions.pingHost(ip, function(error, target) {

    //if error, then examine what type of error has occured
    if(error) {

      if(error instanceof ping.RequestTimedOutError) {
         returnString = "RequestTimedOut";
      }


      //else, different error - output the error string.
      else {
        returnString = "Error";
      }

    } //End error handling

    //else, ping was successful
    else {
      returnString = "Alive";
    }

    callback(null, returnString);
  });

  //return returnString;
}
```

And the code where I call the functions is:

```
var allMachines = new Array();

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('data.txt');
});

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {

  pingFunc(line, function(err, pingResult) {
    SSH(line, function(err, sshResult) {

       var machineTemp = [{'ping': pingResult, 'ssh': sshResult }];
       allMachines = allMachines.concat(machineTemp);
    })
  })
}
```

I plan on later using the `allMachines` array to create a JSON file, however this infinite loop is halting all potential progress. I've tried to move the `connection.on('error', ...)` in the SSH function which I think is causing the infinite loop, however this has proved to be fruitless.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

P.S If anyone knows how I would be able to register when `readlines` has finished, and the `allMachines` array has been filled with the necessary data I would also be very grateful! I've tried to use `readline.on('close', ...)`, however this gets called before SSH and ping finish executing, so is no use to me! Thanks again

Comment: The reason you're having so much trouble is because you are not using the error parameter in your callbacks. The whole point of the first `err` parameter is to pass an error back and check it before continuing on. By passing `null` as your first parameter even if there was an error, you are asking for trouble. I would start there.

Comment: And ` throw err;` in an async callback is absolutely useless.  It does no more than a simple return because it throws into the bowels of some async event callback infrastructure which accomplishes nothing.  You can't use exceptions with standard async callbacks.  As tommy said above, use the error parameter of your callback to communicate errors back.

Comment: Good suggestions, I've modified the code to reflect this, however i'm still getting the same error. Just can't seem to find out what's causing it for the life of me

Comment: "*I use the callbacks to call ping and ssh in a blocking fashion*" - wait what?